# Android turn based game listeners not working

Tags: android, google-play-games

When player take turn, i get notification in the notification bar instead of listening to it in my game while its running

1. Implement **OnInvitationReceivedListener** and **OnTurnBasedMatchUpdateReceivedListener**
2. In **onConnected(Bundle connectionHint)** i added **Games.Invitations.registerInvitationListener(mGoogleApiClient, this)** and **Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.registerMatchUpdateListener(mGoogleApiClient, this)**
3. Override these methods

   ```
   @Override
   public void onTurnBasedMatchReceived(TurnBasedMatch match) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "A match was updated.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

   @Override
   public void onTurnBasedMatchRemoved(String s) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "A match was canceled.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       finish();
   }

   @Override
   public void onInvitationReceived(Invitation invitation) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "An invitation received.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

   @Override
   public void onInvitationRemoved(String s) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "An invitation removed.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   ```

I can't get the code to listen to invitations/notifications that were received.

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting the game by clicking on a notification, the match is passed as the 'connectionHint' to onConnected().  You can check it with code like:

```
 public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected(): Connection successful");

        // Retrieve the TurnBasedMatch from the connectionHint
        if (connectionHint != null) {
            mTurnBasedMatch = connectionHint.getParcelable(Multiplayer.EXTRA_TURN_BASED_MATCH);

            if (mTurnBasedMatch != null) {
                if (mGoogleApiClient == null || !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Warning: accessing TurnBasedMatch when not connected");
                }

                updateMatch(mTurnBasedMatch);
                return;
            }
        }

        // handle registering callbacks and updating status here....
    }
```

The listeners are only needed if you want to handle these notifications in the application when the app is running, so you don't need to have the player go out to the notification bar, through play games, and back to your application.

Comment: Already done, the problem is while the game is running and the other player takes a turn, the game doesn't detect it, and i get notification in the notification bar it's my turn

Comment: You mean onTurnBasedMatchReceived() is not called?  I built the sample and I see the toast message:  Toast.makeText(this, "A match was updated.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    And turn based is enabled in your linked app configuration in the Play Console?

Comment: yes it never get called, turn based and real time enabled, would you mind share the sample you built ?

Comment: I built the SkeletonTbmp sample which is part of https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples

Comment: i built that too, and still got the notification out of the sample xD

Comment: So the call backs are being called.  The notification is shown from the sample. Put a breakpoint in onTurnBasedMatchReceived() and run it in the debugger.

Comment: I figured it out, there was a mismatch between the two certificates, one device was running with the production certificate and the other was using the debug, Thank you Clayton for support